# I want to find the lowest elevation point of a line intersecting a polygon

Tags: arcpy, polygon, line, intersection

I have a rockfall source zone mapped as a polygon at the top of a slope. I created a series of points to represent the polygon boundary and used the python tool (arcpy) arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management to create lines that extend from the points along the aspect or dip direction of the slope. So, the lines extend downhill and some cross multiple parts of the source zone polygon. I want to identify where the lines intersect the polygon at the farthest point downhill, or the lowest elevation. This would identify points along the very bottom of the source zone, which I can then connect to form a line that represents the bottom of the rockfall source zone. The pictures attached demonstrate the result I am trying to achieve.

Is there a tool, or something else I can use to do the following if statements:

- If no intersections, then the starting point of the line is the bottom of source zone
- If one intersection, then bottom of source zone is intersection
- If multiple intersections, then find the intersection that decreases in elevation with distance from the origin, and then lowest elevation intersection is bottom of source zone

[image: conceptual sketch of what code will achieve; stars are the intersection points I want to find/identify]
[image: cross-section view of one issue I may run into, and I want to identify both the starred bsz and the "true bsz"]

Comment: Is there a tool to answer this, no, its a bespoke workflow. Can it be solved yes. I would personally approach it one line at a time, create the intersection points and then measure their position along the line, if I have understood your description you are always seeking the furthest point away from your starting point.